# how to plot non-overlapping rectilinear plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, cad

I have an assignment which requires me to draw a binary tree connecting all nodes in a graph.
I am using pyplot of matplotlib for all the plotting. The main constraint is that the connections are supposed to be rectilinear and non-overlapping. The rectilinear part was easy, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make them non-overlapping. Especially considering that there are 50 nodes to be connected.

For the sake of easier understanding, I have also included the location of the nodes.
[image: Location of the nodes]

Comment: Are you allowed to use dedicated graph modules like igrap\networkx?

Comment: yes !! we can use anything we find convenient as long as we get the necessary output.